# How to get comment from inside a method with phpDocumentor

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

I was wondering if it is possible to get the comment lines from inside the method with phpDocumentor.I do not only comment in the method block but also a lot inside the method it self.

```
class Test {

/**
 * Methdo to test if i get all the text back. 
 *
 * @return void
 */
public method getCommentFromMethod () {
    # Do something 
    $test = time();
    // dont forget to get this text to
    echo 'get the above comment';
    # How can i get this text also to phpDocumentor
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, those inline comments won't get picked up by phpDocumentor.

See here for a list of what you can document:

http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/getting-started/your-first-set-of-documentation.html#which-elements-can-be-documented

Comment: I'd update source to more up-to-date - FIG proposal: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#3-definitions